# Find common elements in two lists when elements contain more than 1 word -Dart

Tags: flutter, list, dart, set

I am trying to build an app that can find specific ingredients in a food item's list of ingredients. 
I have a list of food ingredients called filtered results

```
filtered results: [{key: enriched corn meal corn meal, vegetable oil (corn, canola, and/or sunflower oil
```

I want to find everything in this list that matches my list called `desired strings`

```
desired Strings: [ sesame oil, sesamin,  vegetable oil, canola oil]
```

Currently I am using this method to compare them

```
  Set<String> lowercaseSet1 =
      cleanedUpStrings.map((e) => e.toLowerCase().trim()).toSet();
  Set<String> lowercaseSet2 =
      desiredStrings.map((e) => e.toLowerCase().trim()).toSet();
  Set<String> commonElements = lowercaseSet1.intersection(lowercaseSet2);
```

However my `commonElements` is returning {}
I was able to split the words on spaces in order to compare single word for word and that worked. But the `commonElements` was returning "vegetable" instead of vegetable oil.

How can I find exact matches with more than one word?

Here are the full lists

```
filtered results [{key: enriched corn meal (corn meal, ferrous sulfate, niacin, thiamin mononitrate, riboflavin, folic acid), vegetable oil (corn, canola, and/or sunflower 0il), cheese seasoning (whey, cheddar cheese [milk, cheese cultures, salt, enzymes], canola oil, maltodextrin [made from corn], natural and artificial flavors, salt, whey protein concentrate, monosodium glutamate, lactic acid, citric acid. artificial color [yellow 6]), and salt.}, {key: enriched corn meal (corn meal, ferrous sulfate, niacin, thiamin mononitrate, riboflavin, folic acid), vegetable oil (corn, canola, and/or sunflower 0il), cheese seasoning (whey, cheddar cheese [milk, cheese cultures, salt, enzymes], canola oil, maltodextrin [made from corn], natural and artificial flavors, salt, whey protein concentrate, monosodium glutamate, lactic acid, citric acid. artificial color [yellow 6]), and salt.}]
```

Desired Strings:

```
I/flutter (14679): desired Strings: [value from home page, seed oils, sunflower oil, sunflower lecithin, sesame oil, sesamin, safflower oil, safflower oleosomes, grapeseed oil, grapeseed extract, flaxseed oil, flaxseed meal, chia seed oil, chia seed gel, pumpkin seed oil, pumpkin seed protein, hemp seed oil, hemp seed protein, poppy seed oil, poppy seed paste, mustard seed oil, mustard seed powder, cottonseed oil, cottonseed meal, vegetable oil, canola oil]
```

And I am cleaning my api results with this code:

```
List<String> cleanedUpStrings = filteredResults.toList()
      .map((entry) => entry["key"].toString().toLowerCase())
      .map((s) => s.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[^\w\s,]'),
          ' ')) // Replace characters other than word characters, spaces, and commas
      .toList();
```

I am using the cleanedUpStrings for the comparison to remove any case issues.

Comment: Can you provide actual filtered and desired lists? Maybe the two list don't have common values. Like there is an extra space between two words in one list. In this case the return value will be [].

Comment: These are the actual filtered and desired lists printed to the console. 
I only trimmed the length.

Comment: Can you provide more information about your cleanedUpStrings and filtered results??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below code for find exact matches with more than one word

```
  List<String> uniqueMatches = [];
  // Convert to lowercase for case-insensitive matching
  List<String> lowercasedFilterResult = filterResult
      .map((item) => item['key']!.toLowerCase())
      .toList();

  for (String desiredString in desiredStrings) {
    // Check if desiredString exists in any item of filterResult
    bool matchFound = lowercasedFilterResult.any((item) =>
        item.contains(desiredString.toLowerCase()));

    // If match found and not already in uniqueMatches, add it
    if (matchFound && !uniqueMatches.contains(desiredString)) {
      uniqueMatches.add(desiredString);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List list1 = ["AA", "BB", "CC, "DD"]
List list2 = ["CC", "DD", "EE", "FF"]
commons = []
list1.map((word)=>if(list2.contains(word){
commons.add(word);}))
```

Comment: Thank you, your list works in dart pad but unfortunately is returning the same empty set for my code. I have updated my question with the full lists